# Keybinding for turning on/off a specific layer

Tags: qgis, shortcuts

Is it possible to create a keybinding that will toggle a single specific layer on/off? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: QGIS, sorry! Version 3.24.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following Python script. Just change `LAYER_NAME`

```py
def change_visibility():
    layer_name = "LAYER_NAME"
    project = QgsProject.instance()
    layer = project.mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
    layer = project.layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer)
    layer.setItemVisibilityChecked(not layer.isVisible())
    

shortcut_key = "Alt+1"
shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence(shortcut_key), iface.mainWindow())
shortcut.activated.connect(change_visibility)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Kadir! I'm not that familiar with python script. Where do i add this?

Comment: It works on current QGIS session. After rerunning QGIS you have to rerun the script.

Comment: So i just change the "LAYER_NAME" in line 2 and add the code to the python console? (ctrl+alt+p)

Comment: You could add it to the project's macros as well to restore it when loaded.

Comment: I added it to the python console, and it works now! Thanks guys.